Calculate land surface temperature in GEE
I want to calculate the land surface temperature, but when the equation is run, there is an error in the PV equation.
var emissivity = pv.expression('(0.985 *pv)+(0.960 *(1-pv))+ 4 * 0.01 *(pv(1-pv)))',{'pv':pv});

Error:

Image (Error) Image.parseExpression: Unable to find algorithm: pv.


On a side note: there are too many parantheses in the last part of your expression ... 0.01 *(pv(1-pv)))
